# PHP from shell: Provide environment for enabling $_POST & $_GET superglobals

Tags: php, shell, superglobals

Disclaimer: This one's just for curiosity, I have no actual problem to solve...

When I run a PHP script from the shell, is there a way to provide a process environment where PHP can derive it's `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobals from, just like the process is run by a webserver?

Or asking differently: Can I mock `$_POST` and `$_GET` from outside the script?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. What would you expect `$_POST` and `$_GET` to contain in a cli script since they are there to expose data you get through HTTP (either in the URL ($_GET) or post body ($_POST))? If you want to mock them, just start by setting the values: `$_POST = ['foo' => 'bar'];` etc.

Comment: Yes, I could actually ask how to mock them, but not from inside the script, more like injecting them the exact way a webserver does.

Comment: Create a script, ex: `mock.php` which mocks the variables and then includes the script you want to run. Then you call `mock.php` instead of the other script directly.

Comment: Or use the `auto_prepend_file` setting maybe to get that mocking  ̶b̶i̶r̶d̶ file automatically included before any main script you are running.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Great idea and so simple I can't believe it didn't come in my mind..